# Strange behaviour for Crossfilter group function

Tags: crossfilter

I facing a strange issue using dc.js and Crossfilter. Imagine the following data and code

```
test_data = [{date: d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0100").parse("2014-11-24T12:00:00+0100"), cnt: 1}, 
             {date: d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0100").parse("2014-11-24T11:00:00+0100"), cnt: 2},
             {date: d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0100").parse("2014-11-24T12:00:00+0100"), cnt: 3}],
test_ndx = crossfilter(test_data),
test_dim = test_ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.date; }),
test_grp = test_dim.group(function(d) { return d.getHours(); });
```

`test_grp.all()` returns `[{key: 11, value: 1}, {key: 12, value: 2}]` as I expect.

If I change the last line to

```
test_grp = test_dim.group(function(d) { return -d.getHours(); });
```

`test_grp.all()` returns `[{key: -11, value: 3}]`.

Why doesn't this return `[{key: -11, value: 1}, {key: -12, value: 2}]`?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening off the top of my head, but it seems like a bug. Can you file an issue? https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I just filed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue in crossfilter; I think it's that you are disobeying the crossfilter API, which states:

> Like the value function, *groupValue* must return a naturally-ordered value; furthermore, this order must be consistent with the dimension's *value* function!

https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group

#### Specifically

The order of the values your *groupValue* function is returning are reversed to the order of the values of your dimensions *value* function, due to the minus sign.

I am over-simplifying, but underneath, the crossfilter group is attempting to keep an index of bins in the same order that the dimension has its own index of all values. If the values are out of order in the group's index, it will not be able to determine the bin boundaries correctly. Such simple assumptions are part of what makes crossfilter so fast.

Here is a simpler example not using dates which has the same behavior:

```
test_data = [{date: 12, cnt: 1}, 
             {date: 11, cnt: 2},
             {date: 12, cnt: 3}],
test_ndx = crossfilter(test_data),
test_dim = test_ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.date; }),
test_grp = test_dim.group(function(d) { return -d; });
```

This `test_grp` also contains `[{"key":-11,"value":3}]`

#### Generally

In fact, any `date.getAnything()` function will not generally work in a group value function (with dates for the dimension value function), unless the observations happen to span exactly the Anything.

For example, say you use `date.getMonth()` - if all the days are from one one month, you're fine because the dimension's ordering matches the group's. But if the dates are March 29, March 31, April 1, April 2, crossfilter may decide it can create a group boundary at the end of March 29, and stick the last three dates in the second bin, or a group boundary at the end of April 1 with the first three dates in it.

Again, I'm simplifying and this is not exactly what crossfilter does. But its algorithm is relying on `<` and `<=` working the same way for dimension values as for group values. When this isn't true, it won't detect the problem (because that would be slow) - it will just silently create the wrong aggregation.

As with the common complaint that `NaN` doesn't work because it isn't properly ordered, there is room for a validation library on top of crossfilter. But you'll still need to set up crossfilter according to its assumptions, which make it very efficient for what it does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. I actually simplified my example, my real use case is that I want to group the records by hour and average over these hours. So in the group function I write `function(d) { return d.getHours(); }`, which I think respects the crossfilter API? Still I don't get consistent results with that approach. For the example above, it works, but for my real dataset, it doesn't for some reason I don't get.

Comment: Ah, ok, so this example is not exactly a bug with the negative numbers, but is somewhat surprising behavior. I've never run into it because I usually transform values in the dimension accessor, not the group accessor. Tom, is there any way you can explain a little more about the issue you're seeing with your real data, where something is going wrong without the negation?

Comment: No, I don't think any `date.getHours()` will work **for a group value function** in general - I've expanded my answer. Agree with @EthanJewett that any transformation which affects the order should be in the dimension accessor - e.g. you could create an hoursDimension, daysDimension, but you can't usually create an hoursGroup and daysGroup on top of a timeDimension.

Comment: Ah, of course. That explains it. So we should probably add something to the docs that says to only use group accessors with Math.round, Math.floor, and Math.ceil, as just about anything is going to get you in trouble...